# OTRS outbox: view sent messages

Tags: ticket-system

We use OTRS to communicate with customers. We had a problem with our outgoing mail, and we want to see what mails have been sent out from OTRS. Is there something like an OTRS outbox where I find a history of all outgoing mail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OTRS there are just the entrys in the Ticket. You could get the informations directly on the otrs DB. A better solution would be in your MTA.

Comment: Your answer would be better if it explained this in more detail.